# Django channels: Save messages to database with duplicates when two or more tabs opened

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I'm using this solution for save messages to DB [Django channels: Save messages to database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68850387/21280166)

But I have a problem with duplicates (in DB) when the user (message's author) has two or more tabs opened in the browser with same chat room.

What's wrong? Please help!

```
import json

from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

from .models import Message


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_chat(self, msg, sender):
        return Message.objects.create(sender=sender, msg=msg)

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        sender = text_data_json['sender']
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(self.room_group_name, {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': message,
            'sender': sender
        })

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        sender = event['sender']
        new_msg = await self.create_chat(sender, message)  # It is necessary to await creation of messages
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': new_msg.message,
            'sender': new_msg.sender
        }))
```

Comment: So you not only completely, *letter for letter* copied a piece of code from another user; but then ask others to fix it. Please read the docs; then try to figure it out on your own. Still can't figure it out after? I'll be glad to help. https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ **hint** You are calling the `chat_message` function more than once. You have 3 tabs? It creates 3 models. Would this function perhaps fit in better some other place?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to ask my question in native question but my low reputation rang (as newer user) doesn't allow it. My own solution see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is here.
Don't call **create_chat** (put data to DB) from the function witch send message to WebSocket (to each opened connection / opened browser's tabs).
Just call it from **receive** function.

```
# Receive message from WebSocket
async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']
    sender = text_data_json['username']
    case = text_data_json['case_id']
    chat_type = text_data_json['chat_type']

    @sync_to_async
    def get_user(sender):
        return User.objects.get(username=sender)
    
    @sync_to_async
    def get_case(case):
        return Case.objects.get(id=case)
    
    user_obj = await get_user(sender)
    case_obj = await get_case(case)

    new_msg = await self.create_chat(user_obj, message, case_obj, chat_type)

    # Send message to room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name, {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': message,
            'username': sender,
            'case':case,
            'chat_type':chat_type,
            'time': new_msg.creted_time,
        }
    )
```